# Dynamic GD image width text

Tags: php, fonts, gd, width

I'm trying to spice up my website by using custom fonts for headings. For me, the most appropriate way to do this is using PHP and GD. I have written a little script which will output the dynamic text based on the $_GET value, however sometimes the image is too wide, which moves everything else about.

How can I get the image to adjust the width of it, based on the width of the text? Here is the code I've written so far:

```
<?php
// Settings
$sText = $_GET['t']; // Text of heading
$sFont = "font/AvantGarde-Book.ttf"; // Default font for headings
$sMain = $_GET['c'] ? $_GET['c'] : 0xF2AB27; // Get a font or default it

// Create the image
header("content-type: image/png"); // Set the content-type
$hImage = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 24);
ImageFill($hImage, 0, 0, IMG_COLOR_TRANSPARENT);
imagesavealpha($hImage, true);
imagealphablending($hImage, false);
imagettftext($hImage, 20, 0, 0, 24, $sMain, $sFont, $sText); // Draw the text
imagepng($hImage); // Generate the image
imagedestroy($hImage); // Destroy it from the cache ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out! For anyone else who may have this problem, you need to add:

```
// Calcuate the width of the image
$arSize = imagettfbbox(24, 0, $sFont, $sText);
$iWidth = abs($arSize[2] - $arSize[0]);
$iHeight = abs($arSize[7] - $arSize[1]);
```

Before the imagecreatetruecolor()

Answer (score 4):

The function [imagettfbbox](http://php.net/imagettfbbox) will calculate the size of what the text will be based on the font you picked. Use the results in your call to imagecreatetruecolor.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, it either breaks the image or causes errors?